# How to check that at least one checkbox must be selected in php usnig jquery

Tags: php, jquery, checkboxlist, checked

How can I check that at least one checkbox must is selected in php using jQuery?
I want to show an alert if the user does not mark any checkbox.

Here's the current code that I'm testing, but it always gives an alert.

HTML:

```
<div class="form">
  <form id="dddd" action="action.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkboxlist[]" value="a" checked> a</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkboxlist[]" value="b" checked> b</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkboxlist[]" value="c" checked> c</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkboxlist[]" value="d" checked> d</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkboxlist[]" value="e" checked> e</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkboxlist[]" value="f" checked> f</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkboxlist[]" value="g" checked> g</label>
    </div>
    <p>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Start</button>    
    </p>
  </form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form#dddd").submit (function() {
    if ($('.checkboxlist').is(":checked") == false) {
      alert("Please select at least one item !");
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  });
});
```

Edit based on responses and running
Working code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("form#dddd").submit (function() {
            if($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length) {
                return true;
            } else {
                alert("Please select at least one item !");
                return false;
            }           
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Where have you used class name `checkboxlist` in `<input type='checkbox'...`

Comment: Consider using `radiobutton`s. Their purpose is to force the user to choose exactly one option.

Answer (score 4):

Check the length of `:checked` checkbox like following

```
if($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length) {
    // do your stuff
}
```

instead of

```
if($('.checkboxlist').is(":checked") == false) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for all for answers. I edit my code with working code based on your answers.

Comment: @vjdj that should work and was tested on my own machine. You sure you loaded the jQuery library?

Comment: Now code working, thanks for help. I edit my first post with working code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
if($('input[name^=checkboxlist]:checked').length > 0) {
    alert("success");
} else {
     alert("error");
     return false;
}
```

Comment: There should be a `return false;` after `alert("error");`, otherwise the script will want to continue to execute. Probably `return true;` for success also. But, the former is the most important here.